# Fetch (get) my YouTube channel into my iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, youtube-api

I would like to get my `YouTube` channel videos into my app.

How can this be done? Does the `Youtube iOS API` support this ?? I couldn't find it, all guides talks about videos but not to a specific channel .

I saw an application that is doing that, but I couldn't know how to do it !!

[image: this screen shot for example]

Thanks!

Comment: Check This link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to get [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) done.
2. Do a [channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) request with mine=true.
3. Get [relatedPlayists->uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads) playlist
4. Call [playListItems->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with playlist Id to get videoId.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i think it's helpful. But can I do that without OAuth ??

Comment: You can not do without OAuth2. You have to get user's consent to look into his channel. I'll publish iOS code for this soon.

Comment: many thanks to u, let me know when you publish the code.

Comment: It's on review, will do

Comment: You can just follow our repository. github.com/youtube

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this [page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests)? There is a [sample app](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/YouTubeSample) available for osx which works pretty much similar as it would do in iOS but you'll have to figure it out.

To download search for downloading source from svn command. Similar to git.

Comment: how to download this sample app?

Comment: Gaurav it will be great if you tell me how,because I can't figure it out.

Comment: @SaadChaudhry use this command in terminal `svn checkout http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ google-api-objectivec-client-read-only`

Comment: @SaadChaudhry I guess you are using mac osx, and I believe it has svn command pre-installed or it may be installed using xcode command line utilities.